# How to delete variable from memory

Tags: powershell

In powershell does "del variable:\" delete the variable from memory or just moves a point? I'm not too familiar with powershell memory management. Is there some place I could read up on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just releases a reference (pointer), but you can force garbage collection with `[System.GC]::Collect()`.

[Steven Murawski has a great blog post about this](https://stevenmurawski.com/2009/03/tip-free-up-some-memory/).